# DNS-SD implementation

Tags: c, services, domain-name-system

I am trying to implement DNS-SD, and I understand how it works, but don't really understand the purpose, so I have a few questions about it.

Let us assume that we have two devices on local network, and we registered services both devices provide, how dns-sd really helps us, it just replaces ip:port/path/to/service with some symbolic name? What if we want to use that service in our program, for instance written in C, how we will handle it?

Answer (score 1):

I think google will help you with why you would want to use it https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking#DNS-SD

This is important if you can not define the path to the service ahea of time. For example if your C program is inside a printer and you want anybody on the network to be able to find the printer without knowing its IP address.

This has nothing to do with C itself but is a way to find things in a network regardless of the language used.

Comment: So I will call service browse command and resolve required service with for instance system() function in C?

Comment: @Lazar: Check to see if there is a service discovery library available, then you can use that instead of capturing and parsing the output of `system()`.